# How to repeat a substring of multi line string multiple times?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to write a function that will add records to PostgreSQL tables, given a table users and a record [username1, 21, Man], I would like to get the string

```
"""INSERT INTO users VALUES(
'username1',
'21',
'Man
)
"""
```

This is what I currently have, It doesn't work and I'm wondering what a good way would be to fix it.

```
def add_record(table, lst_of_attributes):
    ln = lst_of_attributes.length
        """
        INSERT INTO {} VALUES(
        '{}', #has to be repeated (ln-1) times
         {}
         )
        """.format(table, *lst_of_attributes)
```

Comment: Try to utilize existing libs like pandas and sqlalchemy. There is to much logic you would require to implement like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def add_record(table, lst_of_attributes):
  sqlstring = f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES("

  for val in lst_of_attributes:
    sqlstring += f"'{val}'," 
  
  sqlstring = sqlstring[:-1]
  sqlstring += ")"
   
  return sqlstring


table = "users"
lst_of_attributes = ['username1','21','Man']

resultstring = add_record(table, lst_of_attributes)

print(resultstring)
```

result:

```
"INSERT INTO users VALUES('username1','21','Man')"
```

**However:**
As others pointed out, there are already existing libraries out there for this kind of operation, which are probably saver and easier. Another way to go for simple additions to a table would be [stored procedures](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/introduction-to-postgresql-stored-procedures/#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20allows%20you%20to%20extend,triggers%20or%20custom%20aggregate%20functions.).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to manually create your own sql strings from variables like this opens yourself up to sql-injection attacks and other bugs.
Always use a library like [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) to handle it.